# Стирается слэш при парсинге json

Tags: android, json

```
JSONObject jsonObjectTop = new JSONObject(body_json_top);
JSONObject data = jsonObjectTop.getJSONObject("data");

String a = data.getString("profile_picture");

avatar.setImageURI(null);
avatar.setImageURI(Uri.parse(a));
mDjName.setText(data.getString("username"));
```

Почему-то после парса json-объекта и выуживания оттуда profile_picture я получаю следующую ошибку:

> BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:/** (No such file or directory)

Выглядит так, будто что-то стирает слэш. Как это исправить?

UPD:

> ImageView: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: https://

Перехожу по uri, которое высвечивается в этой ошибке - в браузере выводится изображение.

Comment: А что в body_json_top? Или хотя бы в data

Comment: да там джейсонина лежит. я решил проблему, использовав Glide. скоро оставлю ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: Вообще советую для вывода изображений пользовтаь библиотеками типа Glide или Picasso, актуально, если у Вас много изображений в приложении, а особенно, если изображения в списках

Comment: Вы меня опередили)

Comment: Они нативно решают вопросы с памятью, корректно парсят ури итд, если честно андроидовскими средствами я работаю с изображениями только тогда, когда иконки добавляю в src кнопок, а в случае тяжелых картинок лучше обращаться к либам